# how to set value of the _geoLoc.City, etc on a textblock on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a module which can get IP address and check the city, state, latitude, longtitude, etc. All codes has no problem but how can I retrieve the data and display them on my TextBlock?

```
    public class TestGeo
    {
        GeoLoc _geoLoc = new GeoLoc();
        internal GeoLoc GetMyGeoLocation()
        {     

            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://geoiptool.com/data.php")) as HttpWebRequest;
                if (request != null)
                {
                    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
                    using (var webResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                        if (webResponse != null)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                                doc.Load(reader);

                                var nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("marker");
                               // Guard.AssertCondition(nodes.Count > 0, "nodes", new object());

                                var marker = nodes[0] as XmlElement;
                                Guard.AssertNotNull(marker, "marker");
                                _geoLoc.City = marker.GetAttribute("city");
                                _geoLoc.Country = marker.GetAttribute("country");
                                _geoLoc.Code = marker.GetAttribute("code");
                                _geoLoc.Host = marker.GetAttribute("host");
                                _geoLoc.Ip = marker.GetAttribute("ip");
                                _geoLoc.Latitude = marker.GetAttribute("lat");
                                _geoLoc.Longitude = marker.GetAttribute("lng");
                                _geoLoc.State = GetMyState(_geoLoc.Latitude, _geoLoc.Longitude);

                                return _geoLoc;


                            }
                        }

                }
                return new GeoLoc();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way of doing that... of course, it's a bit hard seeing as you didn't show us what your `GeoLoc` class looks like.

Start a new WPFApplication and add this to the code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    GeoLoc location = new TestGeo().GetMyGeoLocation();
    LocationTextBlock.Text = location.ToString();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Put this into the XML page between the `<Grid>` and `</Grid>` elements:

```
<TextBlock Name="LocationTextBlock" />
```

Of course, if you haven't overridden the `ToString` method, that won't display anything useful... in that case, either [override `Object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or replace that line in the constructor with this:

```
LocationTextBlock.Text = location.SomeProperty; // Use a string property of your class
```